# How to parse java output to CSV file

Tags: java, opencsv

I have written a code which gives me output as different digit numbers in list form in console. I have created a CSV file, need to parse the numbers to CSV file. I am stuck here. Can anyone please help how to do it. I have just started using stackoverflow, so if there's any mistake please let me know. Thanks for the help.

This is the code that I have tried.

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter

public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        File file= new File("getnumbers.csv");
FileWriter outputfile= new FileWriter(file);
CSV writer writer=new CSV writer(outputfile);
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
          String lookfor="Success :: status 200 Created link on ".toLowerCase();
          System.out.println(lookfor);
          File myObj = new File("test1.txt");

          Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
          while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = myReader.nextLine();
            if(data.toLowerCase().contains(lookfor)){
                //System.out.println(data.toLowerCase().split(lookfor)[1].split(" ")[0]);
                ouput.add(data.toLowerCase().split(lookfor)[1].trim().split(" ")[0]);
            }
          }
          myReader.close();
          for(String t:output) {
              System.out.println(t);
          }
          
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: So if I'm reading you correctly, you simply don't know how to write using OpenCSV Writer?

Comment: I dont know how to fetch the output values and parse to csv.

Comment: OK, so here's what I'm not following in your code sample: what is `get numbers.csv` and then what is `test1.txt`? Which file is providing your input? Maybe you should explain in plain language what it is, exactly, you're trying to do. And maybe explain why there's no call to `write` for your CSV Writer.

Comment: Sorry about that.. test1.txt is  a text file that has the numbers that I got as output. I should parse these numbers to CSV file. So I created a CSV file getnumbers.csv .

Comment: output is the list that contains the numbers. Please can anyone help me about next step?

Comment: I have to disagree with your assessment here... `output` is nothing because you haven't declared it anywhere that I can see. This code won't compile, so maybe you should start by declaring all the variables you use. I might suggest also that you don't need to use OpenCSV at all since you seem to be splitting input data into tokens already. Why not just add commas as necessary and skip using the library?

Comment: You have some typos: ouput -> output

Comment: Okay thanks. Can you please tell me what changes should I make to parse the numbers to CSV .

Comment: So you want to extract number from a text file then save it to csv file? Could you provide the sample content of text file?